# setting every value in a list to something in vb

Tags: vb.net, list, picturebox

Let's say I want to set the property of every item in a list like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim test As New List(Of PictureBox)


    For q = 1 To 25
        Dim picbox As New PictureBox
        test.Add(picbox)


    Next
```

timer tick

```
    test.Item(everything in list).Top -= 3
End Sub
```

Can I do it all at once instead of iterating and setting each value separately?

Comment: there are many issues with that snippet. a) each item in the list refers to the same picture box, so you really only have to set one of them and they will all change. b) to make 25 of them, move the `DIM picbox` statement inside the loop c) then, set their locations to something else they will be in the same location  d) likewise just set the BackColor in the loop as you make them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just update the color before adding it to your list:

```
For q = 1 To 25
    picBox.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
    test.Add(picbox)
Next
```

As an aside, do you realize that you are adding the same item 25 times? If you want different instances you'd need to create a new one in your loop:

```
For q = 1 To 25
    picBox = New PictureBox
    picBox.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
    test.Add(picbox)
Next
```

Just for fun, you could rewrite your entire snippet like so to get a list of 25 PictureBoxes:

```
Dim test = Enumerable.Range(1,25) _
           .Select(Function(i) New PictureBox With {.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue}) _
           .ToList
```

Comment: yeah but if i wanted to set the position of all the picture boxes in the list

Comment: You'd need to set them. If you have some sort of system for determining placement you can calculate the positioning using `q` or `i` depending on which loop structure you use.

Comment: well is there another way

Comment: Probably, but I don't see why you'd want a different way. This is probably as straightforward as you're going to get.

Comment: so i would just do test.item(1).top -= 3 and then test.item(2).top -=3 and so until 25 or what if i had 1,000 items

Comment: Just ask another question if you need more clarification. These follow-up questions are only sort of related to your initial question.